# C# linq Expression Func in select throwing value cannot be null parameter name : source error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am writing simple linq query as below. The first select mapper works fine. But the second mapper class not working and throwing `'Value cannot be null; Parameter name: source'` This is really driving me crazy. Don't know how to debug as pressing 'F11' not going into the method. In the following 'User' class is the data object.

main method which returns the result:

```
    return await query
        .Select(UserSearchMappingSelector.ToDto(hasSensitiveAccess))
        .Select(UserSearchMappingSelector.ToViewModelFromDto(hasSensitiveAccess))
        .OrderBy(user => user.Name)
        .ToListAsync();

public static Expression<Func<User, SearchPersonDto>> ToDto(bool hasSensitiveAccess)
        {
            return (User entity)
            => new SearchPersonDto
            {
                Id = entity.Id,
                UserGuid = entity.UserGuid,
                KnownAs = entity.KnownAs,
                Forename = entity.Forename,
                Surname = entity.Surname,
                Manager = GetManager(entity),
                Subordinates = GetSubordinates(entity, hasSensitiveAccess)
            };
        }

public static Expression<Func<SearchPersonDto, SearchPerson>> ToViewModelFromDto(bool hasSensitiveAccess)
        {
            return (SearchPersonDto entity)
            => new SearchPerson
            {
                Id = entity.Id,
                UserGuid = entity.UserGuid,
                Name = User.GetDisplayName(entity.KnownAs, entity.Forename, entity.Surname),
                Manager = new Manager() { Id = entity.Manager.Id },
                Subordinates = new List<Subordinate>()
            };
        }

public partial class User
{
    // Logic is in sync with [org].[Select_AuditUsers]
    // if KnownAs is empty string DisplayName should be " surname"
    [NotMapped]
    public string DisplayName => GetDisplayName(KnownAs, Forename, Surname);

    public static string GetDisplayName(string knownAs , string forename, string surname)
    {
        return $"{knownAs ?? forename} {surname}";
    }
}
```

Not sure why the second mapper not able to read the manager property from the SearchPersonDto class.

Can anyone please help me what the issue with the above query?

Also if i comment the Manager and Subordinates properties in second mapper, everything is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: `User.GetDisplayName`  is a problem. After that you cannot use all EF IQueryable features. Put `AsEnumerable` before `OrderBy` and check Name for null.

Comment: `GetManager` also problem. EF cannot look into method body and understand which SQL to generate. Try do not mix custom methods with translatable constructions,

Comment: User.GetDisplayName is working fine. When i comment the second mapper everything works fine. So i think the problem is at the second mapper.

Comment: Problem is `OrderBy` on column which is calculated by custom function. Also include call stack - it is source how to resolve issues.

Comment: As I have mentioned, if i comment out the Manager and Subordinates from second mapper, everything is working fine even with Orderby.

Comment: so... does everyone have a manager? can `.Manager` be `null`?

Comment: @MarcGravell not everyone will have a manager. there are few records without manager as well.  I tried with Manager = new Manager() { Id = entity.Manager != null ? entity.Manager.Id : 0 }, but still same error